# Is it possible to make an Android phone act as an NFC tag?

Tags: reactjs, nfc

I'm wondering whether it's possible to make an Android phone act as an NFC tag, so that when another phone "scans" it, they're directed to a website?

And if yes, is it possible to do this via the browser?
For example, Device A opens up my website, I generate an NFC URL and then when Device B "scans" the NFC tag, the URL is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to an Android device to act as an NFC host (you use it when you pay via NFC in the store).

However it is not possible to control it via a web browser. Unfortunately you need an app to make this possible.

Update:

I just looked up, since Chrome 89 on Android there is an NFC API. I don't know if it actually works for your case, but you can check out: https://web.dev/nfc/